# achemso-control with natbib not functioning correctly

Tags: natbib, achemso, txfonts

I am using the `achemso.bst` bib file with natbib, and below is the minimum working example as well as the `achemso-control` entry to reproduce my issues:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letter,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[numbers, super, sort&compress]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{achemso}
\usepackage{txfonts}

\AtBeginDocument{\nocite{achemso-control}}

\begin{document}
    The researcher found a literature procedure.\cite{Betzler2013}
    \bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The achemso-control I am using is in my main bibliography.bib file, but reproduced here to see:

```
@Control{achemso-control,
    ctrl-article-title = "yes",
    ctrl-doi = "yes",
    ctrl-etal-number = 0,
}
```

The first issue is article titles are not appearing even with control. The DOI does appear but is the wrong font. No packages I have used makes any difference on the lack of title appearing.

I have narrowed down the package that causes the issue to be the `txfonts` package causing the issue. This is for a chemistry dissertation; however, I do want the main font to be a Times font. This is the only font declaration in the document, so I'm not sure why txfonts is displaying different Times fonts for different aspects of the reference.

Is there an obvious workaround that I'm missing here for either the font issue or the lack of title display?

bib entry to help:

```
@article{Betzler2013,
   abstract = {<p> The synthesis of the nitrogen‐rich glycidyl‐5‐(carboxyethyl‐1 <italic>H</italic> ‐tetrazole)polymer ( <bold>4</bold> ) by the reaction of glycidyl azide polymer (GAP) and ethyl cyanoformate ( <bold>2</bold> ) is described. Moreover, the polymer precursor 1,2‐bis(5‐carboxyethyl‐1 <italic>H</italic> ‐tetrazolyl)ethane ( <bold>3</bold> ), containing two tetrazole moieties, was obtained by reacting compound <bold>2</bold> and 1,2‐diazidoethane ( <bold>1</bold> ). The substances were characterized by using vibrational spectroscopy (IR), mass spectrometry, as well as multinuclear NMR spectroscopy. Compound <bold>3</bold> was additionally characterized by single‐crystal X‐ray diffraction measurements. The thermal stability of <bold>3</bold> was determined by differential scanning calorimetry, which reveals that this compound is a highly stable molecule. </p>},
   author = {Franziska M. Betzler and Thomas M. Klapötke and Stefan M. Sproll},
   doi = {10.1002/ejoc.201201201},
   issn = {1434-193X},
   issue = {3},
   journal = {European Journal of Organic Chemistry},
   month = {1},
   pages = {509-514},
   title = {Synthesis of Glycidyl‐5‐(carboxyethyl‐1 H‐tetrazole)polymer and 1,2‐Bis(5‐carboxyethyl‐1 H ‐tetrazolyl)ethane as Polymeric Precursor},
   volume = {2013},
   year = {2013},
}
```

Edit for information: There was an extra `achemso.bst` in the directory, which is what was causing the titles to not appear even with an `achemso-control` entry.

this is the `.blg` file:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2023)
Capacity: max_strings=200000, hash_size=200000, hash_prime=170003
The top-level auxiliary file: sandbox2.aux
The style file: achemso.bst
Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=4) to 100 items from 50.
Database file #1: bibliography.bib
achemso 2024-01-30 v3.13g
You've used 2 entries,
            2538 wiz_defined-function locations,
            753 strings with 6697 characters,
and the built_in function-call counts, 537 in all, are:
= -- 40
> -- 20
< -- 2
+ -- 9
- -- 7
* -- 47
:= -- 70
add.period$ -- 2
call.type$ -- 2
change.case$ -- 2
chr.to.int$ -- 1
cite$ -- 2
duplicate$ -- 31
empty$ -- 39
format.name$ -- 7
if$ -- 97
int.to.chr$ -- 0
int.to.str$ -- 1
missing$ -- 0
newline$ -- 34
num.names$ -- 3
pop$ -- 5
preamble$ -- 1
purify$ -- 0
quote$ -- 0
skip$ -- 1
stack$ -- 0
substring$ -- 26
swap$ -- 26
text.length$ -- 2
text.prefix$ -- 0
top$ -- 1
type$ -- 11
warning$ -- 0
while$ -- 6
width$ -- 0
write$ -- 42
```

Comment: please add the bib entry so people can reproduce the problem

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Do you have a problem with the zero in the doi?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry about that, it has been added.

Comment: @Mensch Yes, one of the issues is that I was confused as to why the DOI is a different font than the rest of the reference, if that was some sort of compatibility issue between achemso and txfonts or something else.

Comment: I can't reproduce an issue with title inclusion: can you edit-in your `.blg` file contents?

Comment: you have html matkup in your bibtex abstract?

Comment: @JosephWright I have no `.blg` file being produced, only a `.bbl` related to this. However, I believe I figured out the issue, as I had a `achemso.bst` in the same directory as the `.tex` file, which I didn't realize. Remove this solved the title not being present.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The bib file is currently an unedited export of my Mendeley library, which contains abstracts that I'll probably never touch. Could that cause unforeseen issues if I never use the abstract entry?

Comment: @bbarden OK, probably an older version then - but you must have made a `.blg` to generate a `.bbl` ...

Comment: @JosephWright you're right, it was hidden behind a windows misattribution so I was overlooking it. I have added the `.blg` to the post, even though the issue may be solved already.

Comment: @bbarden yes if the abstract is html it could easily have an unescaped tex syntax character such as `}` that would completely break the bibtex parsing.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't provide an example but the slashed zero is the standard in the monospace font used in `txfonts` (and it's newer replacement `newtx`)

Perhaps you would prefer to set the DOI in sans serif rather than monospace

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

%\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{newtx}



\begin{document}
  0123 \texttt{0123} \textsf{0123}
\end{document}
```

The companion package `newtxtt` actually offers several style of tt 0 of different widths and slashed or not slashed, so choosing a not slashed style

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

%\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{newtx}
\usepackage[zerostyle=a]{newtxtt}


\begin{document}
  0123 \texttt{0123} \textsf{0123}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you happen to know why only the DOI is affected rather than the other numbers that are not controlled by the `achemso-control` entry?

Comment: @bbarden just a choice of the bibliography style you used to set that in tt just as the journal title is in italic.  nothing in your control settings looks font related just setting the fields to be typeset, the style is specified elsewhere